# HTTP request timeout in IONIC APP using Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: ionic2

I developed a mobile application using ionic angular 2 , my question is how to do session timeout when user is idle . I have google and look for possible solution and not understand where I should put the code . Do i need to put in the all page or just in app.component.ts file ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called `ng-idle` that helps to achieve this functionality.

[Have a look at ng-idle2 here](https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng2-idle/)

Also [here](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng2-idle).

I believe this is what you are looking for.